# What are the Types of HTML Page extensions

Tags: html, xhtml, file-format, dhtml

I knew that html page can be saved as `.htm` or `.html`,`.xhtml` stands for extensible html.but i see some other extensions such as `.dhtml`,`.phtml`

Can Anyone explain what it means and different types of html extensions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are as many file extensions related to web pages that I can find which fit the paradigm ".[a-z]html."

**.dhtml** - a text file that contains dynamic HTML code, which is used for developing interactive Web pages that can change without being reloaded or opening another link.

**.phtml** - a text file that contains PHP code. The PHP code is parsed on the web server in order to dynamically generate HTML code. ".php" is much more commonly used for web files containing PHP code.

**.jhtml** - a text file that contains Java code; may include Java functions that are processed on the server before the page is sent to the client's Web browser.

**.mhtml** - Web page archive format saved from a .HTML file and encoded with .MIME encoding. Includes resources linked from the Web page, such as images, Flash animations, Java applets, audio files, etc. Can be opened and viewed without being online. Microsoft Word can save and open MHTML Web archives.

**.rhtml** - Web page containing Ruby code or scripts. It is processed on a Web server running Ruby on Rails before the page is sent to the Web browser.

**.shtml** - Web page written in HTML that contains server side includes. It processed by the Web server before being sent to the users browser. It can reference other files on the server, i.e. "header.shtml" or "_footer.shtml."

**.zhtml** - Web page parsed by RabbitWeb, a Web server that integrates .C program code with special HTML tags. The file contains embedded "ZHTML" commands that are used to generate dynamic content for the webpage.

It should be noted that it is very rarely appropriate to store a file using any of these extensions - ".html" or ".html" are the standards for any text files that are meant to published to the Web. The only exception to this rule might be ".mhtml", which is a format exclusive to Microsoft. However, IMO, ".mhtml" archives are rarely the best solution for saving copies of web pages and their content; it is much better to convert the page to a .PDF file or some other type of file that doesn't store linked resources locally as individual files (which can litter a user's local directory).

Answer (score 0):

A **PHTML** (or it's sometimes called a PHP) page is a Web page that includes a script written in PHP, a language comparable to JavaScript or Microsoft's VBScript.

**DHTML** is Dynamic Hypertext Markup Language.DHTML is Dynamic HTML means HTML+JavaScript. It is referred as a dynamic HTML and dynamic in nature. A page with HTML, CSS, DOM and Scripts called as DHTML.

Answer (score 0):

**.dhtml:**

- Dynamic HTML or DHTML.
- DHTML is generally consisting of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

**.phtml:**

- HTML page that includes a PHP script.
- It is used when you need to add some PHP code in your HTML file.